# Workaround of showing a base64 pdf on IE9+

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, iframe, cross-browser, base64

I would like to convert a PDF to base64 and show on browser.

The problem is , the following code works for Firefox and Chrome

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,encodeString></iframe>
```

But not in IE 9 + , suppose the user is using adobe reader plugin, are there any jquery plugin/workaround that allow embed a base64 pdf on iframe? thanks

Comment: Some approach I can think of , convert base64 to other data format? Are there any format that the IE9+ browser iframe support ? thanks

Comment: Looks remarkably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/16857678/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1038922/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7819366/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7588262/139010.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I have looked at that post and it seems not fixing my problem.

Comment: Thanks for more info. ,  Is that possible to convert the base64 code to some other format (pdf stream ?) and ie9 iframe will support that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Base64 encoded PDF with Internet Explorer 10 and below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154606/saving-base64-encoded-pdf-with-internet-explorer-10-and-below)

Comment: I got it working using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66643440/5719150)

Comment: I got it working with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66643440/5719150)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, Internet Explorer does not support the use of DATA URIs as the source of IFRAMEs. The only workaround for this is to return your PDF content from a HTTP/HTTPS or FTP URI and use that as the source of the IFRAME.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You refer to a PDF in an IFRAME like this: `<IFRAME SRC="http://example.com/my.pdf" />`

Comment: can you please elobarate?

Comment: StackOverflow comment threads aren't really the place for new questions. I'm not sure what elaboration would be helpful: the HTML snippet I provided shows exactly how to create an IFRAME pointed at a PDF.

Answer (score 9):

Note: For IE and other browsers like Mozilla, Chrome this works
for me

```
if (data == "" || data == undefined) {
    alert("Falied to open PDF.");
} else { 
    //For IE using atob convert base64 encoded data to byte array
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var byteCharacters = atob(data);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else { 
        // Directly use base 64 encoded data for rest browsers (not IE)
        var base64EncodedPDF = data;
        var dataURI = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64EncodedPDF1;
        window.open(dataURI, '_blank');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dinesh-rajput, this solution is working for me. I still can't figure out why this should be done on year 2017 ^^

Comment: How would you apply this code to the following file? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-umo7G978pdalJrdVhibHU4Y0k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

For those that run into this issue later on. Dinesh Rajput's answer used to work, but `msSaveOrOpenBlob()` is now deprecated and should only be used on older versions of IE and Legacy versions of Edge. Now you can just set the iframe src to your pdf.

I know this is old, but I have been stuck on this for a while and I figured it out.

The issue is that Edge has a char limit for URIs. You have to turn your pdf into a blob first.

```
//Convert to blob
var byteCharacters = atob(response);
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
     byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });

//Convert blob into URL Object
blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

 //Set URL Object as iFrame src
 document.getElementById('iframe').src = blob;
```

This should actually work for all modern browsers, so no need for browser/feature check.