# Open PDF in base64 format from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf, base64

I have PDF (as base64) document as variable in my page

```
  var base64pdf = "...";
```

And now I want to open it inside my HTML page. I have implemented it in next way:

```
  var $pdfObject = $("<object>");
  $pdfObject.attr("type", "application/pdf");
  $pdfObject.attr("data", "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64pdf);
  // append $pdfObject to some div
```

And this works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but doen't work in IEs

PS. I can't load PDF by adding `src="mypdf.pdf"` attribute

Comment: Might http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627370/workaround-of-showing-a-base64-pdf-on-ie9 help out? Does not seem to be possible...

Comment: Which version of ie ? Tried substituting `embed` element for `object` element `<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="data:application/pdf;base64,.." type="application/pdf">` ? Does ie display any `data URI` other than `.pdf` ?