# pdf not getting embedded in html IE11

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, base64, internet-explorer-11

I want to embed base64 encoded string of pdf into an html template.
`<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64, encodeURI(pdfstring)"></iframe>` 
This works fine in chrome and edge but showing blank page in IE 11.I do not want to download it.Is there a fix for IE11

Comment: Does this help? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627370/workaround-of-showing-a-base64-pdf-on-ie9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because IE doesn't support iframe with data url as src attribute. You could check it in [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri). It shows that the support is limited to images and linked resources like CSS or JS in IE. Please also check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc848897(v=vs.85)):

> Data URIs are supported only for the following elements and/or
> attributes.
>
> - object (images only)
> - img
> - input type=image
> - link
> - CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background,    backgroundImage, and so on.

You can only do what like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627370/workaround-of-showing-a-base64-pdf-on-ie9/18630934#18630934) says:

> The only workaround for this is to return your PDF content from a HTTP/HTTPS or FTP URI and use that as the source of the IFRAME.